# Google "save to drive" button doesn't work in IE11

Tags: google-drive-api

For some reason I can't get the Google "save to drive" button to work in IE11 - it appears as a black triangle with a popup tooltip saying "Save to Drive is not supported for this browser"

[image: IE11: Save to Drive is not supported for this browser (top), and as it should appear (bottom)]

I'm confused as I can't find any reference to this lack of support in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#supported_browsers) (which also appears to refer to the two most recent IE browsers being 9 and 10, but perhaps I'm reading it wrong), and the button appears to work correctly in older and newer versions of Internet Explorer I've tested.

Example page here: http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/analyzing-data-in-the-internet-of-things.csp?download=yes

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#supported_browsers) of Google Drive. The Save to Drive button supports the most recent versions of the following browsers:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- Internet Explorer (which are IE9 and IE10)

In the case of Internet Explorer, I think as of now it is only available in IE 9 and 10.

I also found out that there is an existing [issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3695&q=save%20to%20drive%20button&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner) about this.

Comment: Thanks KENdi - from the looks of the issue you linked to, IE11 support isn't going to be added anytime soon. It's just odd as it works in IE9, IE10 and the new Edge 13 & 14. Ah well, time to write some IE11-specific code to hide those buttons…

Comment: You can comment on that bug report, so that Google will be notified for that issue. And the process of adding it will be faster.